# Need to know in jQuery if a max-width value is in % or px

Tags: jquery, css

There is some way in jQuery to know if the max-width value of a element defined in a css page is in % or px because jQuery always returns the value in px.

I mean....

```
.contain {
   max-width:80%;
}
```

jQuery -> .contain is in %!

```
.contain {
   max-width:80px;
}
```

jQuery -> .contain is in px!

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strange thing is that Louys Patrice Bessette and Mayday are both right.

Mayday's answer is correct... If you test it in Chrome! `.css('width')` will return in `px` (even if set in `%`), whereas `.css('max-width')` will return `%` when using that unit! In Firefox, however, the value is always `px`. You can test this with the code below and open in Firefox as well as Chrome.

```js
console.log($('div').css('max-width'));
console.log($('div').css('width'));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width: 80%; max-width: 80%">
  Bananas
</div>
```

By this we can say that Louys Patrice Bessette was right in poiting out that you cannot do this. That is true, if you are talking about jQuery's CSS method - and probably any getComputedStyle-like method.

What you can do, though, is parse the style sheet and read the actual value that is written in the styles. There are a number of other answers that deal with this, so check them out (you can use the search function to look for more):

- [Parsing CSS in JavaScript / jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3326494/parsing-css-in-javascript-jquery)
- [CSS parser for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963997/css-parser-for-javascript)

Or you can simply read the CSS file as a text file, and then use regular expressions to find the value that you need. (However, this is probably slower or at least more error prone.)

- [How to read text file in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13709482/how-to-read-text-file-in-javascript)
- [Access CSS file contents via JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9180271/1150683)

Comment: Thanks, I've bookmarked this answer for future reference. ;)

Comment: wow! i can see its really complicated my question hehehe... i think this is the way at the moment... thx!

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.contain').css('max-width')
```

It will return you a String, either "80px" either "80%"

Then you can use indexOf to find if there is "px" or "%"

```
if ($('.contain').css('max-width').indexOf("px") !== -1) {
    //is in px
} else if ($('.contain').css('max-width').indexOf("%") !== -1) {
    //is in %
}
```

Comment: Do you know a reference "kind of a list" of these properties we can access to the style sheet definition... Since this solution doesn't work with `width`? It would be usefull... ;)

Comment: Even though this works in Chrome, it does not in Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Citation from the [jQuery `.css()` page.](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

> «The .css() method is a convenient way to get a computed style property (...)»
>
> «Note that the computed style of an element may not be the same as the value specified for that element in a style sheet. For example, computed styles of dimensions are almost always pixels, but they can be specified as em, ex, px or % in a style sheet.»

Here is a test **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/drbnrut0/)** working with the latest jQuery version (3.0.0).

So... Simple answer is **no.**

Comment: Strangely enough, the behaviour differs across browsers. Try this fiddle in Chrome and FF for instance: https://jsfiddle.net/w9ykz72m/

Comment: Wow! Ok then... So next question is : is there a list of these accessible properties ? I'l remove my answer in order to not loose points... But the question remains.

Comment: I decided to undelete... Since Bram Vanroy's anwer is refering to it. For future readers.