# Can i get CSS Property Value of a HTML Element in cheerio

Tags: cheerio

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Hi there.</title>
    <style>
        p {margin: 10px; padding: 20px; width: 500px; line-height: 23px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p>What is the capital of Australia?</p>
</body>
```

How can i get value of margin in the above following code ??

Every time i do the below :
$('p').css('padding')
//i would expect the output to be 20px; but

Im getting the following error:

var styles = parse(el.attribs.style);
^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'attribs' of undefined
at getCss (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\node_modules\cheerio\lib\api\css.js:69:25)
at initialize.exports.css (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\node_modules\cheerio\lib\api\css.js:25:12)
at Node.$.find.each (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\scrape1.js:138:22)
at initialize.exports.each (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\node_modules\cheerio\lib\api\traversing.js:300:24)
at Node.$.find.each (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\scrape1.js:131:16)
at initialize.exports.each (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\node_modules\cheerio\lib\api\traversing.js:300:24)
at Node.$.each (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\scrape1.js:128:12)
at initialize.exports.each (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\node_modules\cheerio\lib\api\traversing.js:300:24)
at Request.request [as _callback] (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\scrape1.js:125:46)
at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\BBNH\Desktop\webscraping\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)

Comment: You would need a css parser for that.

Comment: How to get this and where, can you share me any link where i can find more about this thing ?

Comment: I would use nightmarejs or puppeteer, there's a way to evaluate styles but you need to do the research

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CSS parser for JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963997/css-parser-for-javascript)