# Replacing all ID to Class with certain name using regEx in Sublime Text

Tags: css, regex, class, sublimetext3

I have a huge CSS file and I want to **convert all ID selectors to Class selectors** from a certain name using regEx in `Find and Replace` area in the text editor. I am using `Sublime Text 3`.

In this file, I have some hex colors as expected like `#333 and #ff0000` which need to be considered and the `regEx` pattern should not track it.

### Expected Result

#### find:

```css
#333 /*do not track*/
#ff0000 /*do not track*/
#item1 /*found*/
#item2 /*found*/
#item3 /*found*/
```

#### replace:

```css
#333 /*do not track*/
#ff0000 /*do not track*/
.item1 /*done!*/
.item2 /*done!*/
.item3 /*done!*/
```

*P.S the name either can or not having numbers on it. Need to accept letters and numbers in a way that do not match this hex color pattern above*

What is the best regex pattern to reach this?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you use a CSS parser instead of regex? There could be some element with id `ff0000`.

Comment: This is just for practing my regExs skill sake. I did not hear about CSS parser. it is good to have alternatives. I made a research on it and found [this another question on CSS parser for JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963997/css-parser-for-javascript). They suggest `PostCSS` as a more recent solution. I will take a closer analysis on it. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that maybe, find with,

```
#(?=item\d)
```

or

```
#(?=item)
```

and replace with a `.`.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
> explained on the top right panel of
> [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/QnL4Dy/1/). If you'd like, you
> can also watch in [this
> link](https://regex101.com/r/QnL4Dy/1/debugger), how it would match
> against some sample inputs.

---

### [Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/QwXvLa/1/)

Comment: That did the work with #item+number. But if I for example have only the name without any number (#item) it does not work. Nonetheless, thanks to your further suggestions, I could even find a complementary solution: `#(?=item[\d]?)` for either with or without a number attached to the name. By the way, regEx debugger is something new to me and it rocks. Thanks!